# Do i need a "return" statement when using fetchAll() in a function?

Tags: php, function

I'm testing in PHP a simple function to take data in a faster way, simply putting a query argument and creating an array using fetchAll().

Since fetchAll() is returning an array, do I need the "return" statement or not?

## PHP

```
function data_extraction($query) {
    $query = $co->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    // do I need "return $query"?;
}
```

Comment: that depends on usage of function.

Comment: As @treyBake already said, this depends upon your requirement. Based on what you currently have in your code, you fetch all the results and do _nothing_ with them. I'm guessing you may want to return the results...

Comment: @Martin yes i'm using this function to extract some results that i need to use later in the program.

Comment: You should rephrase the fetch all should be saved in an $array variable which you should return. Returning $query won't get you the desired result. That's why people are downvoting you :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment that:

> i'm using this function to extract some results that i need to use later in the program

It does sound like you need to return the results of `fetchAll()` from the function.

This is easily achieved:

```
function data_extraction($sql) {
    $query = $co->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $arr = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $arr;
}
```

This will return the `array` produced by `fetchAll()` to callers of your function.

Note: You probably don't want to return `$query` as this will give an outside caller access to your prepared statement.

To utilise in your code:

```
...
$results = data_extraction('SELECT xyz...');
```

Replacing the `SELECT xyz...` statement with your chosen SQL statement.

**NOTE**

Following an important comment by @YourCommonSense regarding parameterisation of PDO prepared statements, I urge extreme caution when injecting user content into SQL statements without the use of parameters.  The reference provided by @YourCommonSense is [here](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement) which has a glorious description of the issue and how to resolve it.

This answer is to primarily address the question `Do I use a return statement?` not `How do I safely use PDO prepared statements`

Comment: You can even go further and make it shorter `return $co->prepare($sql)->execute()->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Comment: @DamianDziaduch you, actually, cannot

Comment: In its current form, it's a [cargo cult prepared statement](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo/cargo_cult_prepared_statement). Consider making it a proper prepared statement

Comment: Thank you Martin and @DamianDziaduch for the answers.

Comment: @YourCommonSense unless $query = plain SQL (as in, without any user input)

Comment: @treyBake *especially* when $query = plain SQL

Comment: @Fax As YourCommonSense has stated, this is poorly implemented because it doesn't explicitly define parameters which are safely included in the SQL statement.  I urge you to read the link they provided to help write correctly parameterised PDO (although this is beyond the scope of your question).

Comment: @YourCommonSense wait, really? Someone can sql inject `select * from table`?

Comment: @treyBake a cargo cult is not about injecting. it's about mimicking some behavior thinking it will do you any good

Comment: @YourCommonSense thank you very much for the link, it really help me for a lot of things about PDO.

Comment: @YourCommonSense ahhh I'm with ya know^ :)